python import: automatically add work folder path to sys.path
I note a strange performance when using relative import in python. Here is a example:
Directory structure in D:\tmp\:
example
--level_1_a
----a1.py
--level_1_b
----b1.py

Here are the contents in each py file:
a1.py:
print('------------------------')
print('now is running a1.py')
print('------------------------')

import sys
print('print sys.path in a1.py------------------------')
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
print('------------------------')

import level_1_b.b1

b1.py:
print('------------------------')
print('now is running a2.py')
print('------------------------')

import sys
print('print sys.path in b1.py------------------------')
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
print('------------------------')

Here are the running output when running the a1.py in different work folder path.
The default terminal in Windows 11 is used.
Running test 1:
The work folder is the  C:\Users\Chen_Laptop>, and the module level_1_b can not be found.
C:\Users\Chen_Laptop>"C:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/python.exe" d:/tmp/example/level_1_a/a1.py
------------------------
now is running a1.py
------------------------
print sys.path in a1.py------------------------
d:\tmp\example\level_1_a
C:\MyApps\sumo-1.10.0\tools
D:\LasVSim_v2.0\lasvsim\utils
C:\Users\Chen_Laptop
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python39.zip
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9\lib-dynload
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9\site-packages
------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\tmp\example\level_1_a\a1.py", line 10, in <module>
    import level_1_b.b1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'level_1_b'

Running test 2:
The work folder is the root of the folder: D:\tmp\example>, then it goes well.
It should be noted that these two tests are conducted in the same terminal and I just cd to the root folder of the example.
D:\tmp\example>"C:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/python.exe" d:/tmp/example/level_1_a/a1.py
------------------------
now is running a1.py
------------------------
print sys.path in a1.py------------------------
d:\tmp\example\level_1_a
C:\MyApps\sumo-1.10.0\tools
D:\LasVSim_v2.0\lasvsim\utils
D:\tmp\example
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python39.zip
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9\lib-dynload
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9\site-packages
------------------------
------------------------
now is running a2.py
------------------------
print sys.path in b1.py------------------------
d:\tmp\example\level_1_a
C:\MyApps\sumo-1.10.0\tools
D:\LasVSim_v2.0\lasvsim\utils
D:\tmp\example
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python39.zip
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9\lib-dynload
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\lib\python3.9\site-packages
------------------------

Please note that the #4 in the printed sys.path, the work folder path is automatically added to the sys.path in my computer.
The #2  'C:\MyApps\sumo-1.10.0\tools' and #3  'D:\LasVSim_v2.0\lasvsim\utils' in the printed sys.path, are added in my system environment variables of PYTHONPATH. The PYTHONPATH env variable has only the two items.
The other path after #4 is the interpreter path, which used a python in Inkscape app.
It seems that the performance of python in my computer is different with normal. I have read related questions and people said that the work fold path will be added by add some code in the python file. However, in my computer, it seems that no matter where I run the script, the work fold path will be added to the 'sys.path'.
The terminal is the default terminal in window 11.
python version = 3.9.7
There is a reverse question , and the second answer seems have similar performance like me. But this is actually abnormal, which can be reflected by see the comments to the answer.
I know that the performances in my computer is abnormal and it should no work. But I still want to know what happend.
